# Underlying Hamiltonians and pulse level controls of different commercially available quantum computers

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices, hamiltonian, quantum-control, rigetti

My research area is in quantum state transfer, and I am trying to perform a 'proof of principle' that requires the underlying Hamiltonians of quantum systems and the control I can have on these systems using pulse-level controls.

For example, for an IBMQ device, I can get the (approximate form of the) underlying Hamiltonian with the code:

```python
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
from IPython.display import display, Math
prov = provider.backends(simulator=False) #list of providers I have access to
ham = prov[0].hamiltonian
display(Math(ham['h_latex']))
```

Which gives the Hamiltonian of the form:
$$H/\hbar = \sum_{(i,j)\in E}{J_{ij}(X_iX_j + Y_iY_j)} + \sum_i{B_iZ_i} + \sum_i{\Omega_i(t)X_i}\,.$$
Using pulse level control, we can control $X$ pulses. I am interested in how I can possibly access this kind of information for other systems such as (but not limited to) Rigetti.

Answer (score 0):

This hamiltonian is a *very* basic approximation of the underlying device and in general does not accurately reflect the complexity of the device. It is up to each provider to decide whether to return this information and many hardware providers do not.