# How does one realize quantum gates on actual quantum devices?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-operation, experimental-realization, ibm-quantum-devices, hardware

I am interested in understanding the process of implementing quantum gates on actual quantum hardware such as those developed by Google, IBM, and others.

My current understanding is that each hardware platform possesses a device Hamiltonian that governs the underlying physics of the system. For example, certain devices may follow an Ising chain Hamiltonian with exclusively nearest neighbor interactions. Additionally, there seem to be adjustable knobs in the lab, possibly controlled by some classical magnetic fields on local terms in the Hamiltonian. By combining these factors—local operations and multiple interaction terms—one can construct some quantum circuits.

Although my understanding is quite shallow (I apologize if it's entirely not true!), I'm very curious to learn more about the specifics behind these hardware platforms. If my guess is somehow correct, can someone please guide me to relevant resources that talk about the Hamiltonians utilized by e.g. Google's Sycamore processor or IBM's quantum devices? (and moreover, physical reasons behind specific forms of Hamiltonians?) If not, I would appreciate insights into how one can effectively implement quantum gates. Thank you so much in advance, and I apologize for pretty (dumb!) question :)

Comment: You may be interested in this question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/35018/1837 (not that there are lots of helpful answers!)